# Song from Rebbi Meir Shapira

Tags: rabbis, song-poetry

I have a script of a song from Rebbi Meir Shapira of Lublin which starts with

מיט דער כתר התורה

Are any of our readers familiar with the words or the tune which is supposed to accompany them?